# What is a full code of {"456"} for transform: (String) -> String in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

`transform` is lambda fun with the definition `(String) -> String`

I was told that `{"456"}` is a valid value of `transform`, what is a full code of `{"456"}` for `transform: (String) -> String` ?

Is Code A correct?

**Code A**

```
val aa="123".myAdd{a:String -> "456"}
```

**Code B**

```
val aa="123".myAdd{"456"}

fun String.myAdd(transform: (String) -> String ) = this + transform(this)
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to use a transformation when you're just appending Strings?

Comment: Thanks! transform only is name, I only is to test

Comment: I think your question could be more clear. Because it looks like you're wanting to create a lambda to append a String. Are you trying to modify the String at all, or just append it? `123` + `456` Or are you trying to do something else, and append the result of that?

Comment: You know that `{ it + "456" }` is the same as `{ x -> x + "456" }`, right? `{ "456" }` is just that without `it +`, i.e, `{ x -> "456" }`.

Comment: Thanks! This code is only for practice

Comment: To Naetmul: Thanks!  so is `val aa="123".myAdd{a:String -> "456"}` right too?

Comment: @HelloCW. Yes. `{ ... }` without a parameter list can also mean zero-parameter function, although this is a different situation from the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your example code, let me try to explain what it's doing.

```
val result = "123".add { it -> "456" }

fun String.add(transform: (String) -> String ) {
    this + transform.invoke(this)
}
```

First, you're creating a `String` "123", and you're calling a lambda on that. Now, within your lambda, `it` will be this "123" String.

Normally, you would modify this input in some way, such as a `List.Sort()`, but you're actually throwing away that input and just returning "456". The last line of your lambda is the return.

For example, we could take the "123" input, and increment each number. This would take your `String`, convert it to a `List` of chars, then increment each char, and then join them back together.

```
val result = "123".add { it -> it.map { it.inc() }.joinToString(separator = "") }
```

The lambda is taking a `String`, "123", and applying your transformation and returning a new `String`. (`(String) -> String`) I believe that should take "123" and return "234", which will be appended to "123". "123234".

Does that help explain how the lambda `(String) -> String` works?